# Scan the Android class path for classes with annotations

Tags: android, annotations, classpath

I'm looking for ways to scan the class path for annotations.  This is on the Android platform, which is why all the standard methods I've found so far don't seem to be working.

The only solution that I found that seems to work is this: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/737/android-hacks-scan-android-classpath/ but it's more of a hack than a solution so I'd rather not take that route, plus that solution actually loads all the classes.  I'd prefer a solution that scans for the annotations without loading the classes.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421085/implementing-spring-like-package-scanning-in-android